How to read SQL database with Polars
I am trying to read a SQL database that contains a username and a password. I did:
import polars as pl

server = serveur # confidential 
user = user # confidential 
password = password # confidential 
database= database # confidential 

conn_str =f"mssql://{user}:{password}@{server}/{database}?encrypt=true"

query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[my_table]"
df = pl.read_database(query=query, connection_uri=conn_str)

I get an error message which is:

TypeError: read_database() got an unexpected keyword argument 'connection_uri'

How is it then possible to read a SQL database from Polars?

There're 2 (currently, polars v1.7.0) different ways to connect to MS SQL DB from polars:
1. Using ODBC connection string / SqlAlchemy connection.
Method is called read_database() and it has connection parameter:

An instantiated connection (or cursor/client object) that the query
can be executed against. Can also pass a valid ODBC connection string,
identified as such if it contains the string “Driver={…}”, in which
case the arrow-odbc package will be used to establish the connection
and return Arrow-native data to Polars. Async driver connections are
also supported, though this is currently considered unstable.

Simple example of ODBC connection usage might look like:
conn = """
    Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
    Server=server;
    Database=db;
    Uid=username;
    Pwd=password;
    Trusted_Connection=yes;
"""

df = pl.read_database("select * from table", conn)

You can see possible parameters for your connection string here - sql server connection string.
2. Using connectorX or adbc engine.
Method is called read_database_uri. It accepts uri parameter:

A connectorx or ADBC connection URI string that starts with the
backend’s driver name, for example:

“postgresql://user:pass@server:port/database”
“snowflake://user:pass@account/database/schema?warehouse=warehouse&role=role”

The caller is responsible for escaping any special characters in the
string, which will be passed “as-is” to the underlying engine (this is
most often required when coming across special characters in the
password).

In theory this should work, but I couldn't make it work on my machine so far (I am not the only one - see github.com):
conn = "mssql://user:pwd@server:port/db"

pl.read_database_uri("select * from table", conn)

See some information about connectorx here - MsSQL Connection.

if i have a password to the database. How should I do ?
From your code, I had to put:
Server=; Should I need to put the serveur name between <> ?

@jacques see updated answer

server, db, username and password are between " " or not ?
I tried it but get an error message:
Error: ODBC emitted an error calling 'SQLDriverConnect':
State: 01000, Native error: 0, Message: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' : file not found

@jacques it looks like the problem with the driver - for odbc you need to have driver installed. I’ll update the question later.

Using a connection string, connecting to a MS SQL Server could look as follows.
import polars as pl

user = user # confidential 
password = password # confidential 
server = server # confidential 
database= database # confidential 
trusted = 'no' # or yes

connection = f'mssql://{username}:{password}@{server}/{database}?driver=SQL+Server&trusted_connection={trusted}'

df = pl.read_database(
    "SELECT * FROM table",
    connection,
)

